# diagonal averaging of matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

let us consider following matrix

```
A=[1 2 3 4;2 4 6 7;3 1 9 8]

A =

     1     2     3     4
     2     4     6     7
     3     1     9     8
```

size of which can easily be  calculated using

```
n,m]=size(A)

n =

     3


m =

     4
```

let us consider that we  want to get following vector  v

```
v(1)=A(1,1);
v(2)=(A(2,1)+A(1,2)/2;
v(3)=(A(3,1)+A(2,2)+A(1,3))/3;
v(4)=(A(3,2)+A(2,3)+A(1,4))/3;
v(5)=(A(3,3)+A(2,4))/2;
v(6)=A(3,4);
```

definitely we need  vector with size

```
v=zeros(n+m-1,1);
```

i have  calculated first two element which seems  trivial

```
v(1)=A(1,1);
v(2)=(A(2,1)+A(1,2))/2;
```

but all others i need to implement using cycles,please pay attention that i need it for  general matrix  using same principle,not  exact for such matrix

my  starting code is following

```
function [v]=dehankel(A);
%convert matrix A  to  vector using diagonal averaging
[n,m]=size(A);
v=zeros(n+m-1,1);
v(1)=A(1,1);
v(2)=(A(2,1)+A(1,2))/2;
for i=2:3
    for j=2:3
```

please help me  how to continue

Comment: You could use `diag` on transposed submatrices.

Comment: how exactly ?which part  do you mean?

Comment: Rather than having to write out `(A(3,1)+A(2,2)+A(1,3))` you could do `sum(diag(A(1:3,1:3)'))`(untested), which would let you use loop indices to control the submatrix range. It would save you some bookkeeping, though there'd be plenty still left...

Comment: Actually no, transposing doesn't help, you'd have to rotate it with `rot90` instead: `sum(diag(rot90(A(1:3,1:3))))`

Comment: or `flipud(A)` instead

Comment: @Dan I think `flipud` reads better, probably the numbers in the function name cause some kind of cognitive dissonance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A =

     1     2     3     4
     2     4     6     7
     3     1     9     8

[n,m]=size(A);
v=zeros(n+m-1,1);
i = 1;
for d = -(n-1):(m-1)
    v(i) = mean(diag(flipud(A),d));
    i = i+1;
end
```

Comment: Looks like it to me - why don't you test it?

Comment: i have tested thanks but you know i need average ,so i should include function mean right ? or?

Comment: i am checking and it seems to work,@Dan what does  diag(flipud(A),d)); do?

Comment: Why don't you look at the documentation of `diag` and `flipud`? [`diag`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) extracts diagonals, [`flipud`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html) flips a matrix upside down

Comment: or a one-liner: `v=arrayfun(@(d) mean(diag(flipud(A),d)), -size(A,1)+1:size(A,2)-1)`

Answer (score 2):

It can be done without loops (not the most readable code, I admit):

```
B = zeros(size(A,1)+size(A,2)-1, size(A,2));
B(bsxfun(@plus, (1:size(A,1)).', (0:size(A,2)-1)*(size(A,1)+size(A,1)+1))) = A;
v = sum(B.')./[1:size(A,1) size(A,1):-1:1];
```